# How do I mention the direction of neighbours to calculate the glcm in skimage/Python?

Tags: python, scikit-image, glcm

I'd some trouble understanding the `angle` parameter of `greycomatrix` in skimage. In the example mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycomatrix) to compute GLCM's for the pixel to the right and up, they mention 4 angles. And they get 4 GLCM's.

```
>>> image = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
...                   [0, 0, 1, 1],
...                   [0, 2, 2, 2],
...                   [2, 2, 3, 3]], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> result = greycomatrix(image, [1], [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4], levels=4)
```

What should be the parameters for the pixel to the right and down?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the example included in the [documentation of `greycomatrix`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycomatrix) (emphasis mine):

> **Examples**
>
> Compute ***2 GLCMs***: One for a 1-pixel offset to the right, and one for a 1-pixel offset upwards.
>
> ```
> >>> image = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1],  
> ...                   [0, 0, 1, 1],
> ...                   [0, 2, 2, 2],
> ...                   [2, 2, 3, 3]], dtype=np.uint8)
> >>> result = greycomatrix(image, [1], [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4],
> ...                       levels=4)
> ```

Indeed, `result` actually contains **four different GLCM's** rather than two. These four matrices correspond to the possible combinations of one distance and four angles. To calculate the GLCM corresponding to *"1-pixel offset to the right"* the distance and angle values should be `1` and `0`, respectively:

```
result = greycomatrix(image, distances=[1], angles=[0], levels=4)
```

whereas to calculate the GLCM corresponding to *"1-pixel offset upwards"* the parameters should be `1` and `np.pi/2`:

```
result = greycomatrix(image, distances=[1], angles=[np.pi/2], levels=4)
```

In the example, `distances=[1]` and `angles=[0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4]`. To select a particular GLCM one has to specify the appropriate indices for `angles` and `distances`. Thus, the 1-pixel to the right GLCM is `result[:, :, 0, 0]` and the 1-pixel upwards GLCM  is `result[:, :, 0, 2]`.

Finally, if you wish to calculate the *"1-pixel offset downwards"* GLCM (↓) you just have to transpose the *"1-pixel offset upwards"* GLCM (↑). It is important to note that in most cases both GLCM's are very similar. In fact, you can ignore the order of the co-occurring intensities by setting parameter `symmetric` to `True` in the call to `greycomatrix`. By doing so, al the GLCM's returned by `greycomatrix` are symmetric.

Comment: awesome answer. Im currently trying to figure this out. Could you expand on the 'levels' parameter also?

Comment: According to skimage [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycomatrix): *The input image should contain integers in [0, levels-1], where levels indicate the number of grey-levels counted (typically 256 for an 8-bit image). This argument is required for 16-bit images or higher and is typically the maximum of the image. As the output matrix is at least levels x levels, it might be preferable to use binning of the input image rather than large values for levels.* The value of `levels` determines the size of the gray level co-occurrence matrix.

Comment: You may want to take a look into [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365953/black-line-in-glcm-result/43036067#43036067) to gain a deeper insight into the `levels` parameter.

Comment: Thanks - really useful. Im getting a lot of black space in my image and I'm not entirely sure whats going on so I'll post a new question on this

Comment: I posted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266623/black-space-in-glcm-image - if you are able to take a look